# How do I find records from one collection based on field of other collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

How do I find records from one collection based on field of other collection in MongoDB
(e.g collection A and collection B have a common field as userid just like primary-foreign key concept in SQL)

Like in MYSQL I can use a join query

```
SELECT * FROM a
inner join b on a.id=b.id
where id=12
```

How can this be achieved in MongoDB?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this in MongoDB by using aggregate query it can be used to fetch data from two collections.

Link to documentation:-https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/

```
 db.collection(a).aggregate([
        {'$match':{id:12}},//Optional if you want or you can leave empty
        {'$lookup':{
            from:'b',
            localField:'id',//fildname of a
            foreignField:'id',//field name of b
            as:'details'
        }}
])
```

OR

If you are using some framework like Node Js and you have provided proper reference while creating schema you can populate documents from another collection to another

Link:-https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply...but it creates an extra field called details.. doesn't filter out data..can you provide other query?

Answer (score 2):

As MongoDB is a NoSQL database so there is NO INNER JOIN, but still you can use lookup
to achieve your goal.
In lookup, the **as** field specifies where you want your data it can be a new field or you can replace the existing field.

Your conditions can be fulfilled of filtering data by simply adding **$match** in last

```
db.collection(a).aggregate([
        {'$match':{id:12}},//Optional if you want or you can leave empty
        {'$lookup':{
            from:'b',
            localField:'id',//fildname of a
            foreignField:'id',//field name of b
            as:'details' // you can also use id fiels it will replace id with the document
        }},
        { $match : { "details" : { $ne : []}}}
])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it's useful. Also, can you please share a query to delete the result from this query? I'm new to Mongodb and facing issues in building query.

Comment: Do you want to delete some documents from a database or just delete documents from the filtered query results?

Comment: My final goal is- I have two collections say A and B, with a common field say id, I want to delete records from collection A which don't have id present in collection B

Answer (score 1):

aggregate returns a POJO object so deleting is not possible on it but you can still achieve this by simply writing two query first is aggregate and second is deleteMany

```
db.collection(a).aggregate([
        {'$match':{id:12}},//Optional if you want or you can leave empty
        {'$lookup':{
            from:'b',
            localField:'id',//fildname of a
            foreignField:'id',//field name of b
            as:'details' // you can also use id fiels it will replace id with the document
        }},
        { $match : { "details" : { $eq : []}}}
])

db.collection(a).deleteMany({id:{$in:[array of ids you get from above query]}})
```

I am little unsure about this if it works.
Also please upvode my answers bro which was useful for you or helped you.

Comment: Okay thanks! I'm new to stackoverflow hence my vote is not shown!

Comment: No Problem brother. I hope i might me able to help you.

Comment: Yes  bro,it did help